# OOP php: Method recursion returns null

Tags: php, oop, recursion

I created a method for making auction names websafe, and i just added a check for dupplicate webnames, which basicly tries to fetch an auction with the given websafe name, then adds a random number to the webname. But the method ends up returning null...

```
private function dupplicateUrlFix($url){
    var_dump($url)//Correct
    $existingAuction = Auction::get($url, "webname");

    //if webname exists, cancatenate with random int, and check if new webname exists
    if(!empty($existingAuction->webname)){
        $newUrl = $existingAuction->webname.rand(0,9);
        $this->dupplicateUrlFix($newUrl);
        return;
    }
    var_dump($url) //Correct Not a dupplicate
    return $url;
}

public function get_url_clean($string) {
    $string = strToLower($string);
    //cleaning....
    //checks for dupplicate
    var_dump($this->dupplicateUrlFix($string)); //is null?
    die();

    return $clean;
}
```

I have tried switching the order in the dupplicateUrlFix() method and simply returning a string. It only goes into the if(!empty... one time.

Is there a solution for this, or a better approach?

Comment: I don't think `$existingAuction->webname.rand(0,9)` is valid. Perhaps do `$newUrl = ($existingAuction->webname).rand(0,9)`

Comment: @Doctus It makes more visual sense spaced as `$newUrl = $existingAuction->webname . rand(0,9)` <- concatenation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's subjective - they're both valid

Comment: @Doctus I didn't say your was invalid. I thought you implied it was invalid because the dot was intended as a class operator. I misread your comment.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! Yeah I'm not exactly sure, but I know in the past when concatenating object properties with strings I've had to wrap them in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no need for recursion here:

```
private function dupplicateUrlFix($url) {
    $existingAuction = Auction::get($url, "webname");
    while (!empty($existingAuction->webname)) {
        $url = $existingAuction->webname . rand(0, 9);
        $existingAuction = Auction::get($url, "webname");
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! it even looks alot cleaner :)

Comment: It can be even converted to `do .. while` so as not to write `$existingAuction = ...` twice)

Comment: You'll have an infinite loop when you hit the 12th name. And assuming the get() method hits a database, you'll have an infinite loop hitting the database.

Comment: Still we can add some counter to `while` to e.g. throw exception when number of attempts exceeded.

Comment: rand(0, 9) returns one character. So, you'll get the base name foo plus ten extra names foo0, foo1, etc. After eleven attempts, you have no more names to try.